# image links in php functions

Tags: php, image, function, hyperlink

i have a question for you that i need help with.
i have a function that prints out a link

```
$text .= "<br><a href=page.php?view=1>page</a> - (<b>$out[1]</b>)";
```

that prints a link to page.php like  'page'

i would like to have an image instead of a word,

i tried to insert one like;

```
$text .= "<br><a href=page.php?view=1><img src="boat.gif" alt="Big Boat" /></a> - (<b>$out[1]</b>)";
```

but it gives me an error unexpected t string.

any ideas on how to do this?
thank you in advance for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text .= "<br><a href=page.php?view=1><img src=\"boat.gif\" alt=\"Big Boat\" /></a>
 - (<b>".$out[1]."</b>)";
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the quotes, you have to escape them:

```
$text .= "<br><a href=page.php?view=1><img src=\"boat.gif\" alt=\"Big Boat\" /></a> - (<b>$out[1]</b>)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$text .= "<br><a href=page.php?view=1><img src=\"boat.gif\" alt=\"Big Boat\" /></a> - (<b>$out[1]</b>)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes in your variable $text.

```
$text .= "<br><a href=page.php?view=1><img src=\"boat.gif\" alt=\"Big Boat\" /></a> - (<b>$out[1]</b>)";
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please also quote the string in the `href` part of the `a` .

Try the below code

`$text .= "<br><a href='page.php?view=1'><img src='boat.gif' alt='Big Boat' /></a> - (<b>$out[1]</b>)";`